# Improving debugging of symfony applications with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I have some problems debugging my symfony 1.4 applications with eclipse.

I am using:

- eclipse helios
- XDebug as PHP Debugger
- Default PHP Web Server

When I am starting symfony like this:

```
http://myURL/frontend_dev.php/event?XDEBUG_SESSION_START
```

everything works fine but when I click on the id to edit, it 'forgets' that I am in the debug mode. Of course I can change it manually back by typing

```
http://myURL/frontend_dev.php/event/1/edit?XDEBUG_SESSION_START
```

but that's annoying, if you debugging this several times.

Concatenating an equals value, e.g.

```
http://myURL/frontend_dev.php/event?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1
```

only works for the next page and after that the session and the cookie is gone.

Knows someone what happening there? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I got same problem with sf2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a debug session, `XDebug` writes a cookie that expires after an hour, or until there is a call with XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP (see http://xdebug.org/docs/remote). So, basically, your debug client should get a hit no matter what.

That leads me to believe you are probably not starting the session as you should, that is through an eclipse (PDT, or any other) `PHP Remote Launch Configuration`. If you just trigger the session-start using a URL, the client (eclipse) might not be ready to accept any further calls after the first hit.

Let me know if that helps, or you need any more clarifications.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the hints, sgibly but unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. Even, if the cookie is set (by adding equals=1: XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1), it only works for the next page, then it is deleted again.

Comment: So the cookie is getting deleted? That may happen because the client sends a termination event. Open Eclipse's Debug perspective and take a look at the launch stack. Do you see a launch that says 'Terminated'? Also, did you try using browser helper plugins, such as the XDebug Helper?

Comment: The launch stack looks alright, there is no 'Terminated' but obviously the debug session is. I tried easyXdebug (the follow-up of XDebug Helper) but doesn't seem to be worth it.

Comment: Did you try using the PDT's `Remote Launch Configuration`? I looked at the PDT's code, and the start `URL` is a little more complex, so you can try do the same - `...?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=1234`. The `ECLIPSE_DBGP` is the IDE key, and the `1234` represents a random/sequential session ID. The stop URL is also a little different - `...?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=1234`. Can you try something like that?

Comment: Also, double check your `php.ini` to include these: zend_extension_ts=<full path to the xdebug .dll/.so>
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, sgibly. Much appreciated! I checked everything: It's all fine. I also tried the different call you suggested, unfortunately it does not solve the issue either.

Comment: Running out of ideas :-) The last thing I can think of (for now) is that something in the browser side reset that cookie. Can you try debugging using a different browser. Long-shot, but you never know... ;)

Comment: Yes, this is a really annoying problem, which is still existing when I change from Firefox to Chrome, which I have already tried.

Comment: ok. One more try - Go to the XDebug configuration dialog in the preferneces (under PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers). There is a JIT setting there. Try to turn it on for localhost. Also, turn on 'multisessions'

Comment: I already tried this but unfortunately it does not work, neither with 'localhost' nor with 'any'. The same with 'multisessions'. There is no change in behaviour. Do you have the same issue, when you are debugging symfony with eclipse or does it work fine for you? I just ask, because reinstalling of eclipse unfortunately also did not change anything.

Comment: Hmm, I actually developed part of the PDT debugger support, and most of the Aptana's previous PHP debugger :-) I'll need to set up symphony on my system and try it out. The thing is that I can't see any major difference when running symphony or any other PHP code. The server side, and the xdebug extension, should intercept any request. The XDebug should trigger a session request as long as the cookie is there. Until I do that test, have you ever tried using ZendDebugger, or are you restricted to xdebug?

Comment: No I haven't. It is my work computer and all in the company use xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your php.ini

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1;
```

This will tell XDebug to profile every page.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything. I Have still the same issue. Thanks for your suggestion!